# Which function is called each time url changes in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have to make a queue of all requests simultaneously happening without waiting for the response from the previous request in angularjs.
I have a loading function which shows the loading div each time I change the url route but its not ok to make an arrray of queue in that function.
 Can anyone tell me which function is called in angularjs routes when each time I change the url route ?
 HEre is the routes code :

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.directives', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.filters']).config(
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

        var loading = function (data, headersGetter) {
            $('loadingDiv').show();
            return data;
        };
        $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(loading);

        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'elements/home/home.html',
            controller: homeCtrl
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
.run( function($rootScope, $location) {
   $rootScope.$watch(function() { 
      return $location.path(); 
    },
    function(a){  
      console.log('url has changed: ' + a);
      // show loading div, etc...
    });
});
```

Comment: but $scope is not defined in routes.

Comment: you are right, I've edited the answer, $rootScope instead, in a Module.run() initialization function

Comment: Thanks.. it works but now i want the list of all pending requests in routes or in controller any where.. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 24):

`$route` service has a series of events you can monitor using `$.on` in a controller:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(args){})

$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess"....

$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError"....
```

See doc **[$route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)**

You could set `ng-show` on your element instead of using jQuery and set the variable to true in `$routeChangeStart` callback and false in `$routeChangeSuccess` callback.

A good demo for these events: https://github.com/johnlindquist/angular-resolve